# cut a char in a string

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring, split

I have a string

```
string = "01";
```

but I want to delete the '0' and have a new string with only '1'. Is there a fast solution?

Comment: and for 12 u want to have o/p as 2??? or want to remove zeros only?

Comment: What do you mean by **fast** ?

Comment: Is string a C string, or is string an NSString object? Here it is written as a C string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:-

```
    NSString *string=@"01";
    NSString *temp=[string substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, 1)];
    NSLog(@"temp%@",temp);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
-(NSString *) substringFromIndex: i
```

Returns a substring from the character at i to the end

```
-(NSString *) substringWithRange: range
```

Returns a substring based on a specified range

```
-(NSString *) substringToIndex: i
```

Returns a substring from the start of the string up to the character at index i

And if you only want to remove 0's before any nonzero value then make a

```
int i = [str intValue];
str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the leading zero from an arbitrary length NSString object you could do:

```
NSRange aRange;
aRange.location = 0;
aRange.length = 1;
[theBreakerCode stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"0" withString:@"" options:NSLiteralSearch range:aRange];
```

Strings without a leading zero are untouched.